# high quality, complicated django projects to learn from

Tags: django, django-generic-views

What are some of the opensource django projects that are well designed and written and could benefit learners. For example, if I want to learn more how classy generic views work in the field, I'd like to see how it's implemented in a large website.

Comment: Have you seen this list? https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources#Open-SourceDjangoprojects

Comment: @Gareth Lloyd - Some of these projects are really old and do not reflect some of the new mechanisms implemented since django 1.2 and 1.3

Answer (score 1):

ReviewBoard is one I have had a look at a couple times - https://github.com/reviewboard/reviewboard